# Error: < marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag. Did you mean LT or LTE?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I am getting the following error. The website is currently running on ColdFusion 10 server. It used to be running ColdFusion 6. Is this issue caused by the upgrade of ColdFusion versions?

> < marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag. Did you mean LT or LTE?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you show us the code that is throwing the error? Otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

That issue should not be caused by an upgrade of ColdFusion versions.  You did not supply any code example.  Please show us the code that is being referenced by that error.

Typically the "did you mean LT or LTE" error is in reference to the `<cfif>` tag.  In ColdFusion, with the `<cfif>` tag, the conditionals are `LT` instead of `<` and `LTE` instead of `<=`, etc.

My guess is that you have some code like this:

```
<cfif myvariable < 10>
```

When the code should look like this:

```
<cfif myvariable LT 10>
```

*If you post your code then we can be more helpful.*